# User Profile Service Application SPPrefix issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, autospinstaller

I am currently trying to install SharePoint 2016 using AutoSPInstaller, the only issue I have is that when it tries to Create the User Profile Service Application I get the following error:

> New-SPProfileServiceApplication : Cannot find SPPrefix object with Name : personal.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Service application command is looking for the managed path "Personal" which is not exist.

Now, check the MySite web application and make sure the personal managed path should be exist.

go to `central admin > Application management > Select Mysite webApplication` and in ribbon click on Managed Path.